# Call Jenkins CLI from within pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to call Jenkins CLI commands within a pipeline?

Upon migrating jobs to new Jenkins instances I would like to enable users to migrate their own jobs from an old Instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write pretty much any shell code you want, including calling the CLI jar from a shell instruction.

```
sh "java -jar /path/to/jenkins-cli.jar your-usual-command"
```

Comment: Note that this lead me to wondering if I could avoid the dependency on the installation location of that jar and requiring, say, a tool configuration to make it maintainable w/i undue changes to the pipeline.

To that end, I looked up the source of Jenkins to find the class and package name for the CLI Java class containing the main method so that I could attempt to invoke it directly, assuming it would be in the classpath of the Groovy runtime, e.g.:

`script{  hudson.cli.CLI.main(null) }`

Don't do this.  After adding a script approval for it, it crashes Jenkins.